# color style not work on chrome but it work on firefox

Tags: javascript, css, regex, arabic

i want to change color Arabic character(mark) by regex in js
it worked on firefox and change color `ٍ` mark to red but no work on chrome

this is my code:

```js
let str = "شَيْءٍ ";
str = str.replace(/(\u064D)/g, "<span class='redcolor'>$1</span>");
document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.redcolor {
  color: red;
  -webkit-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Assign font-size

```js
let str = "شَيْءٍ ";
str = str.replace(/(\u064D)/g, "<span class='redcolor'>$1</span>");
document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.redcolor {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

Comment: by  Assign font-size it work on chrome but is separated characters of one word( colored characters) in firefox